# Use Mathf.PingPong() from current position

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to use Mathf.PingPong() from the current x, y and z coordinates and let it move along the x axis however now it moves too far and too fast. I know how I can speed down but what about the distance?

```
       transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * speed, 1), transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of PingPong is the length, so you can adjust that to your desired distance.

```
transform.position += new Vector3(transform.position.x + Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * speed, length), transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
```

Also another way to write this would be:

```
transform.position += Vector3.Right * Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * speed, length);
```

Also: I noticed you're adding it on to the current position, but PingPong never returns less than zero so your object won't move back and forth if that's what you were intending (?) if so you could subtract half the length from the result of PingPong first: `transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + (Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * speed, length)-0.5*length), transform.position.y, transform.position.z);`

Comment: Suddenly it says that it can't convert from double to float why?

Comment: Because `0.5` defaults to `double` and `double` * `float` = `double`, which won't automatically/implicitly convert back to `float` to protect against precision loss. Change it to `0.5f` to say you want a `float`. Also, you'll probably want to cache the starting point of your PingPong, eg. `Vector3 startPoint = transform.position;` in `Start()`. Then in `Update()`, `transform.position = startPoint + (Mathf.PingPong(...)...);` Otherwise the origin of your PingPong will change over time in a feedback loop.